# Adding delay between dynamically mapped tasks in Airflow 2.3.4

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have a dynamic task and a Big Query operator that gets fed the results from the dynamic task. I want to know how to add a delay between each mapped tasks as I'm hitting rate limit errors.

```
@task
def f():
    return [{configurations...}]

configurations = f() # list of about 5K configurations 

# this is where i want to have a delay between each insert call to Big Query 
insert_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(task_id="task"...).expand(configurations=configurations)
```

Tried the above which led to 400 rate limit errors. Is there something simple where I can add a delay between each mapped task?

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest built in function to rate limit would be utilizing pools:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/pools.html

Pools help more with concurrency but if you set the pool limit low enough, the restriction will spread out the tasks over time. You will be increasing the total run time for the DAG with this approach though.

The proper way would be getting the operator to handle the Rate Limit error itself. This could either be modifying the operator itself, or modifying the hook if it uses one. Both have their pros and cons.
Assuming this is from a package, either approach would involve creating a custom operator/hook and then adding code to catch the error.

If you modify the operator you can use self.defer to trigger the deferring of the operator.

Modifying the hook will be the more complicated approach as a hook can not trigger a defer, so you would need catch the rate limit error and then throw a special error that the operator knows means to defer itself. We built one called DeferException that our operators watch for. This approach requires modification to both operator and hook.

Deferring Operators:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/deferring.html

Comment: Note that [Airflow Pools do not currently work with deferrable operators](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/21243), although there's [a PR open to support this functionality](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/32709)

Comment: They still work with pools, but don't hold a slot in the pool when in a deferred state. Once that PR is accepted, pools will definitely a lot better at helping with rate limiting, but they still can help now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#placing-limits-on-mapped-tasks), there are two ways native to mapped tasks to limit the number of parallel mapped tasks:

1. Globally limiting the number of mapped tasks that `expand` can create by setting [max-map-length](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-map-length) (1024 by default on Airflow 2.3.4)
2. Limiting parallel copies of a mapped task by passing `max_active_tis_per_dag=<max parallel mapped tasks>` to `expand`

Alternatively, as mentioned by @Tevett Goad, you could use [Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/concepts/pools.html) to limit a particular set of tasks across all DAGs.

Using retries combined with passing `retry_exponential_backoff=True`, `retry_delay=<retry delay>`, and `max_retry_delay=<max amount of time to wait between retries>` could also provide some relief (although this might not be a good idea with 5k mapped tasks!).